# finding and asymptotic expansion for a function $f(z)$ as $z \to a$ where $f(z)$ has a branching singularity at $z=a$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

I think looking at a particular example would be very helpful for me; let's take this example : What is an asymptotic expansion for the function $$f(z)=e^{\sqrt{z}}$$ as $z \to 0$ ? If it matters at all, I am taking the negative real axis as the branch cut for $\sqrt{z}$. any help is appreciated

Comment: $1+\sqrt z+z/2+z\sqrt z/6 + \ldots$

Comment: @mercio Thank you ! I know that you have used $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$$ which is the Taylor series of $e^x$... although here we CAN'T use the Taylor expansion of $e^{\sqrt{z}}$ (because the function is not analytic at in a nbhd of zero), it seems like it gives us the correct asymptotics.... why did you expect that it gives the correct asymptotic series, is there a theorem ?!

Comment: @the8thone, merio's series is equal to $e^\sqrt{z}$ by definition, and since $z \to 0$ iff $\sqrt{z} \to 0$, mercio's series is an asymptotic series for $e^\sqrt{z}$ as $z \to 0$ for the same reason that $1+x+x^2/2+\cdots$ is an asymptotic series for $e^x$ as $x \to 0$.